# How can I enable logging with Ninject?

Tags: log4net, ninject, nlog

Is there a way to get Ninject to log out what it is doing?

In particular I'd like to see when objects are being created.  As I have a mix of transient and singleton objects it'd be very useful for me during debug to be able to see how many instances of each are being created so that I can fix object scopes where needed.

**EDIT:** N.B. I'm looking at Ninject 2 as found at http://github.com/ninject/ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1.x answer: Yes, via log adapters for a.o. log4net and NLog - see http://mhinze.com/logging-with-ninject/

[in response to comment] EDIT: v2.0 Beta answer: No:-

From [Ninject 2 Reaches Beta!](http://kohari.org/2009/02/25/ninject-2-reaches-beta/)

> *Things that were in Ninject 1.x that are not in Ninject 2:*
>
> **Logging infrastructure**: Cut because it wasn’t really useful anyway. Ninject doesn’t generate logging messages of its own anymore, but I’m looking into alternative sources of introspection.

...

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I'm looking at Ninject2 which no longer takes a logging module as an argument to StandardKernel's constructor.

Comment: thanks, I missed that one..  I have just been reading the source though and did notice the lack of any logging.

Comment: @chillitom: And I was had actually typed in but deleted "Why not look in the source - its not exactly big and it's very readable!" - just as well I retracted that!

Comment: It has now been ported.  How useful it is I don't know yet :)  https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the new web site you will see a list of extensions. 2.0 RTM is out and the extensions are being released one at a time, but you can still user them. The logging extension is [here](http://github.com/idavis/ninject.extensions.logging) and you can track the number with a static object and provide a lambda expression to increment it in .OnActivation(...) during binding.